# How to find next best (suboptimal) solutions using PuLP?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I created an objective and constraints using PuLP and it gives the optimal solution (a maximization), which is wonderful.

However, it would be useful for me to know the next few solutions that are not the absolute best.  Essentially, I want to do the following...

1. Solve LP and get maximum objective value (I did this)
2. Use this maximum value as a constraint to limit the objective value in future solutions
3. Repeat process a number of times, each time lowering the maximum objective value

After a solve, I've tried adding a constraint that uses the objective equation in an inequality (limiting the maximum value of the objective), but I get this error:

> UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective.

Also, the new solution has an objective of "None".  I've read that this error often comes up when you accidentally create a constraint without an inequality.  My constraint definitely has an inequality.

Is there a better way to do this that I don't know about?

```
new_model = pulp.LpProblem("NBA stats optimizer", LpMaximize)

# create binary lpVariables for every pairing
pfs = [LpVariable("pf{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(pf_pairs))]
sfs = [LpVariable("sf{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(sf_pairs))]
pgs = [LpVariable("pg{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(pg_pairs))]
sgs = [LpVariable("sg{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(sg_pairs))]
cs = [LpVariable("c{}".format(i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(len(c_singles))]

# add objective
new_model += sum(x1 * pts1 for x1,pts1 in zip(pfs, [row[0] for row in pf_pairs])) \
             + sum(x2 * pts2 for x2,pts2 in zip(sfs, [row[0] for row in sf_pairs])) \
             + sum(x3 * pts3 for x3,pts3 in zip(pgs, [row[0] for row in pg_pairs])) \
             + sum(x4 * pts4 for x4,pts4 in zip(sgs, [row[0] for row in sg_pairs])) \
             + sum(x5 * pts5 for x5,pts5 in zip(cs, [row[0] for row in c_singles]))

# create a constraint that each set of pairings has only 1 group at a time
new_model += lpSum([pfs[i] for i in range(len(pf_pairs))]) == 1, "pfLimit"
new_model += lpSum([sfs[i] for i in range(len(sf_pairs))]) == 1, "sfLimit"
new_model += lpSum([pgs[i] for i in range(len(pg_pairs))]) == 1, "pgLimit"
new_model += lpSum([sgs[i] for i in range(len(sg_pairs))]) == 1, "sgLimit"
new_model += lpSum([cs[i] for i in range(len(c_singles))]) == 1, "cLimit"

status = new_model.solve()

new_model += (sum(x1 * pts1 for x1,pts1 in zip(pfs, [row[0] for row in pf_pairs])) \
              + sum(x2 * pts2 for x2,pts2 in zip(sfs, [row[0] for row in sf_pairs])) \
              + sum(x3 * pts3 for x3,pts3 in zip(pgs, [row[0] for row in pg_pairs])) \
              + sum(x4 * pts4 for x4,pts4 in zip(sgs, [row[0] for row in sg_pairs])) \
              + sum(x5 * pts5 for x5,pts5 in zip(cs, [row[0] for row in c_singles]))) \
              < float(value(new_model.objective))

status = new_model.solve()
```

Comment: A warning is not an error. But in your case this warning means you are not doing what you tried to do (you don't want to touch the objective). Why? That's unclear without seeing any code. The approach actually might also not do what you want to do. What about solutions with an equal objective? You are not guaranteed to find those when lowering the obj-constraint and without lowering, you are not guaranteed to find the other solutions (might hit the same sol every time).

Comment: @sascha... Thanks for your help.  I found a way to get solutions with equal objective.  (I iterate through each group that is part of the solution and create a constraint that keeps them out of the next solution, thus revealing other solutions with the same objective.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why I was getting the warning was because my new constraint was an inequality without an equals sign.

> I had to change "<" to "<=".

Changing this one thing got rid of the warning.

However, adding the "<=" inequality meant that my constraint would not be limiting the objective value through each iteration.  (It could return the same objective value over and over again.)  I next added a small decrement to the constraint on the right side of the inequality...

> <= float(value(new_model.objective)) - 0.01

However, @sascha's comment is a good one and adding the "- 0.01" would force the solver to skip two different solutions with the same objective value.

So, I came up with a different approach.  I would not allow the same five pairings that created the current solution to appear together in another solution.  This way, solutions wouldn't repeat.  After each iteration, I sum up the binary variables' values for the five pairings.  (These binary variables indicate whether this pairing is present in the current solution.)  I don't want all five to appear together again (this would be a repeat solution), so I create a constraint to ensure their sum is less than five.  A value of five would indicate that all of them are present again.  The new constraint takes this form:

> new_model += pfs[cur_pf_group] + sfs[cur_sf_group] + pgs[cur_pg_group] + sgs[cur_sg_group] + cs[cur_c_group] <= 4.9

Here, the 4.9 is better than 5, because we just need the sum to be 4 or less.  Using 5 here would allow the same solution again.